# Where could I look online to learn about being a game designer?

Tags: game-design

I'm interested in being a video game designer but I know next to nothing about how to do what ever it is I will be doing as a game designer. Could you offer any advice of a good online area where I could learn about the basics of game designing and later on the more complicated information.

Comment: Online as in free, or as in paid courses etc.? Just game design, or also development (any part of the development process)?

Comment: apart from learning the concepts, methodologies on game desgin, I strongly suggest you to play LOT of games of ALL genres.

Answer (score 4):

I happen to have a list of such links on my website: http://www.newarteest.com/game_dev.html

The most helpful resource for someone in your position (ie. interested in but has no idea what video game designers do) is the first one on the list: http://www.sloperama.com/advice.html

Answer (score -3):

http://www.gamedev.net/forum/31-for-beginners/

Comment: If you need to pad your answer out, then it's a bad answer.

Comment: I didn't really feel a bunch of fluff was necessary to explain why gamedev.net was useful for learning to develop or design games. but for the sake of not padding my answer I put the specific link I went to when I was in Matthew's situation. The lack of explanation was also being lazy because I figured this would get closed since the question is about opinion, still I thought one of the most useful links would suffice.

Comment: @brandon: Posting a complete sentence is just common courtesy. And now your answer should be made a comment.

Comment: @NicolBolas, if the moderators want to change it they can feel free. I wrote it like that because I went to a QA site a long time ago and was given that exact answer in that form and it helped immensely, but next time I'll make sure and add some fluff to put their minds at ease... In my mind, if they asked "Where can I go to get an overview of any topic on the web?" I would say "wikipedia.org". Since Matthews questions is basically gamedev.net's mission statement, I still think it's valid and don't care to change it.